# The definition of support of distribution and support of continuous functions are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am reading several books about distribution theory (or generalized function theory). For a distribution $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n),$ some books define its support set as follows:

$\textbf{Definition1:}$  Support of $u$ is intersection of all closed set $K$  satisfying $(u,\phi)=0$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\text{supp} \phi \in K^c.$

On the other hand, for a continuous function $u \in C(\mathbb{R}^n),$ the classical definition of its support is

$\textbf{Definition2:}$  Support of $u:=\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}}$.

I am curious that are the two definitions equivalent when $u$ is a distribution and also a continuous function?

For certain $x$ in the support set of $u$ under Def 1, then $x$ is in the intersection of all the closed set $K$ satisfying $\int u\phi \ dx=0$ for any $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(K^c),$ thanks to the continuity of $u,$ we have $u=0$ on $K^c.$ Then $x$ is in the intersection of all the closed set $K$ where $u$ is zero on the open set $K^c.$ Thus I need to show that
$$
\cap_{K}\{K:K \ \text{is closed,}u|_{K^c}=0\}=\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}}.
$$

Clearly,
$$
\cap_{K}\{K:K \ \text{is closed,}u|_{K^c}=0\} \subset \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}},
$$
since $\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}}$ is a closed set **where u vanishes on its complement.**(Is it true? To prove the bold sentence, should I need to use the fact that $u$ is continuous?)

On the other hand, for every closed set K where u vanishes on its complement, we have
$$
\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}} \subset K.
$$
Therefore we conclude that
$$
\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\neq 0\}} \subset \cap_{K}\{K:K \ \text{is closed,}u|_{K^c}=0\}.
$$

My question is the above deduction is right? And how to clearify the bold sentence in my deduction? Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: By definition of the support, a function vanishes on its complement. If you're not sure about it, try to prove it via contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems like this property is deduced from the definition not from the continuity of $u.$ So I guess the only place I need the continuity is $\int_{K^c} u\phi=0, \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}(K^c)$ to deduce $u=0$ on $K^c.$